# How to extract exif data from shape using vba Excel 2010?

Tags: excel, vba, metadata, exif

The project I'm working on imports images from a blob in a MySQL database. Sometimes these images are rotated 90 degrees and the user needs to manually rotate them to the correct orientation.

So my question is, is anyone aware of a function that extract exif data from a shape in Excel using vba? I'm trying to avoid any third party applications to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I eventually turned something up in the bowels of social.msdn.microsoft.com.

Here is the solution. Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation reference required. Credit to OssieMac on social.msdn.microsoft.com. [Link to page of post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/435c30c5-0baf-4e14-aedf-fad90bdae4d3/excel-vba-specialnonprinting-characters-in-string?forum=isvvba)

Pointing it at a shape doesn't seem to work (gives me an error), but I save my mysql blob to a temp file on the pc anyway so this works out for me anyway.

```
Sub ListMetadata()

Dim fileFolder As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim objShell As Shell32.Shell
Dim objFolder As Shell32.Folder
Dim objItem As Shell32.FolderItem
Dim i As Long

'Edit following line to your path. (Note NO back slash on end.)
fileFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Picture Test"

'Can insert path like following if you prefer.
'fileFolder = "C:\Users\OssieMac\Documents\Excel\Test Macros\Picture Test"

'Edit following line to your file name
fileName = "DSC00093.JPG"

Set objShell = New Shell
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fileFolder)
Set objItem = objFolder.ParseName(fileName)

With objFolder
  For i = 1 To 1000
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A") = .GetDetailsOf(objItem.Name, i)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B") = .GetDetailsOf(objItem, i)
  Next i
End With

Set objItem = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing

End Sub
```